# Force.com Sites session expiry

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

We have a requirement to show a visualforce page using force.com sites in a TV. The records will be refreshed every 5 seconds. Is there any concept of session expiry while having the site open the whole day. 
If so, are there methods that can be called to prevent it

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: No. As per my knowledge when your VF pages are exposed publicly, through sites no session expiry is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions only expire when they're not actively being used. If you're refreshing every 5 seconds, your session won't expire. If you're not using logins, though, it won't matter anyways. Do keep in mind that Sites are limited in total CPU time, bandwidth, and page views, so you might want to reconsider the 5 second refresh time if many different devices will be using the same page.